# My new PCIe card doesn't fit into my motherboard; whose fault is it?

Tags: installation, motherboard, pci-express, capacitor

A capacitor on my motherboard (an Asus Prime A320I-K) is preventing the PCIe card from going completely into the slot (and against the support bracket). The card can tilt about the point where the card meets the capacitor. The motherboard only has the one PCIe slot that I'm trying to use.

**I need to resolve this, but I'm not sure whether to return the card or the motherboard.** I also wonder which specification I should look for (if any) in either product to ensure physical compatibility.

Please see the diagram:

[image: Diagram of the PCIe card sitting on the motherboard]

Comment: If the capacitor's leads cannot be bent to move it out of the way, the best solution may be to have the capacitor replaced with one that keeps it clear of the card's pathway - I'm unsure if ASUS provides motherboard warranty service like this _(server board manufacturers often do, but unsure about desktop)_, else an electronics repair company that does onsite PCB soldering, such as [UBreakIFix](https://www.ubreakifix.com/), can _(do not unsolder/resolder it yourself, as you have no way to ensure proper connection to the circuits between the PCB layers)_.

Comment: @JW0914 There's no "slack" in the capacitors leads that would make it possible to bend. I contacted Asus and while they do offer an RMA program, they could not guarantee that my board was defective or that a replacement board would be any different. Furthermore, I would be responsible to pay for the shipping both ways; from Germany to USA and back again. I ended up returning the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was mostly the card, somewhat the board; connecting the original card via a PCIe riser cable yielded mixed results: it was detected inconsistently but the ports never worked. I bought a different X1 card that fit and worked perfectly, however it had noticeably more clearance around the previous collision area than the original card.

Most of the reviews for the original card are positive, so it seems to me that my board isn't capable of supporting all PCIe card form factors, and that the original card was on the upper end of size and required clearance. Separately, the original card was defective or used a chip (RTL8111G) that the 4.9+ and 5.9+ Linux kernel didn't have support for (despite the product page claiming the opposite).

Answer (score 0):

The PCIe Electromechanical Specification is what you want to refer to.

It defines what kind of shape the card is allowed to have, and since such a card must fit into the motherboard, also things such as motherboard allowed component height around the slots is defined by the specification.